# Redirect to another page after order status change

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, hook

I have a payment system in my wordpress woocommerce store, after they choose the payment method, they are taken to a screen with the payment details to transfer the money. After the payment is completed, the order status is changed automatically and I need to redirect them to the thank you page after the order status is changed

I tried putting the redirect code inside this hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function( $order_id ){ //redirect code here }
```

but the redirect doesn't work at the same moment, for the redirect to happen the user needs to refresh the page. I need to do the redirect without having to refresh it

What hook should I use to activate when the order status changes and make the code redirect the page for this order to the thank you page? because I tried another hook that was activated when the order changed, but this made the admin screen where you edit the products redirect to the thank you page, not the screen the customer sees with the payment details

if someone can help me I will be extremely grateful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use code like this :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'ak_javascript_redirect_from_the_thankyou_hook', 10, 1 );

function ak_javascript_redirect_from_the_thankyou_hook($order_id){
   $order = wc_get_order($order_id); //<--check this line

    $orderstatus = $order->get_status();

    if (($orderstatus == 'completed')) {


    echo '<p>Thanks for your order you will be redirected to the woocommerce.com site in 5 seconds.</p>';
    $link_redirect  = 'https://woocommerce.com/';
    ?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = '<?php echo $link_redirect; ?>';
            }, 5000);
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
}
```

Comment: Hello, where should i put my conditional if inside this code for the code only trigger when the order status change? one of my if codes for exemple is ` if ( $order_status == 'completed' ) `

Comment: I edited my code and added condition, please check it now

Comment: Hello, thanks! yeah the condition is working fine now but i'm still with the same problem: the user needs to reload the page to be redirect, the code don't load if the user don't take action

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody need the code exactly lik Richard wanted, this worked for me:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'ak_javascript_redirect_from_the_thankyou_hook', 10, 1 );

function ak_javascript_redirect_from_the_thankyou_hook($order_id){
   $order = wc_get_order($order_id); //<--check this line

    $orderstatus = $order->get_status();

    if (($orderstatus == 'completed')) {


    echo '<p>Thanks for your order you will be redirected to the woocommerce.com site in 5 seconds.</p>';
    $link_redirect  = 'https://woocommerce.com/';
    ?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = '<?php echo $link_redirect; ?>';
            }, 5000);
        });
    </script>
<?php
        
        
}
    
    { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 8000);

</script>
<?php }
    
}
```